# Running multiple async readers are not running asychronously

Tags: c#, async-await, ado.net

In the below code I'm trying to run three queries asynchronously. When they start it's definitely asynchronous in that it says 'start sync1, start sync2, start sync3' and this is immediate. When I run it non-async I get 'start sync1, end sync1, ... as you'd expect.

But it seems to be then running ExecuteReaderAsync in series for each call, waiting on each one to finish before starting the next and taking the exact same time when I run them sequentially and waiting the same time between each.

My Sql server is enterprise 2017 on another server.

I appreciate async is about non-blocking tasks but after each started simultaneously I was expecting each of the three tasks to complete at about the same time. Instead while they started together, the actual commands executed seemily synchronously, one after the other, taking the same time.

Can somebody explain how the code below is actually running from an async point of view and why it isn't doing what I expected?

Even if I change the execute statement and wrap it in a Task.Run() to put it in the threadpool I get the exact same response.

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncSample
{
    internal class Tester
    {
        internal void Run()
        {
            AsyncTests();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async void AsyncTests()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var overallStart = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Task<bool> async1 = RunASync1();
            Task<bool> async2 = RunASync2();
            Task<bool> async3 = RunASync3();

            await Task.WhenAll(async1, async2, async3);

            var overallEnd = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - overallStart;
            Console.WriteLine($"Sync test took {Math.Round(overallEnd / 1000.0, 1)} seconds.");
        }

        private async Task<bool> RunASync1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   async1 start");
            await RunASyncQuery("SELECT TOP 10000 * from TABLE1");
            Console.WriteLine("   async1 end");
            return true;
        }
        private async Task<bool> RunASync2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   async2 start");
            await RunASyncQuery("SELECT TOP 10000 * from TABLE2");
            Console.WriteLine("   async2 end");
            return true;
        }
        private async Task<bool> RunASync3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   async3 start");
            await RunASyncQuery("SELECT TOP 10000 * from TABLE3");
            Console.WriteLine("   async3 end");
            return true;
        }

        private async Task<bool> RunASyncQuery(string sql)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Asynchronous Processing=true";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `async != parallelism`

Comment: yes, thanks for your detailed answer ;-) 

I know async is not parallelism, it's non-blocking. So I presumed it would (especially with running on the Thread Pool) to be able to run all 3 given the server is more than capable, and it is definitely starting all 3 together, just then running 1 query at a time blocking the others. I'd just like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try to use different connections or enable [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)?

Comment: Dont await these  `await RunASyncQuery("SELECT TOP 10000 * from TABLE1");`  Just return the task.

Comment: The fact that the asynchronous execution time is similar to the synchronous doesn't necessarily mean that the tasks run one by one. There is big unknown - the amount of data you're retrieving from db. With relatively big size of a record, 10000 records can form significant amount of data which may create bottleneck on the transition phase (not query execution). That is your queries can be executed simultaneously and fast enough by server but amount of data may make a transfer congestion which in turn may lead to similar to execution time similar to the synchronous execution.

Comment: @Lee, what do you mean?